# Toggle Tree List Branches in Backone and Marionette

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a nested Tree list using Backone and Marionette.  I would like to toggle the view of each Branch that has a leaf by clicking on the branch `li`.

There is a bug when I click on the second level nodes in the tree to expend them.  Clicking the `Car` or `Truck` node ends up closing the branch instead of opening the next level.  I am not sure how to fix this bug.

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/aeao3Lec/

Here is my JavaScript, Data, and Templates:

JavaScript:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TheModel,
});

var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    mainRegion: '.main-region' 
});

var TreeItemView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        if ( this.model.get('children') ) {
            this.collection = new TheCollection( this.model.get('children') );
        }
    },

    tagName: 'ul',

    className: 'tree-list',

    template: _.template( $('#tree-template').html() ),

    serializeData: function () {

        return {
          item: this.model.toJSON()
        };
    },

    attachHtml: function(collectionView, childView) {
        collectionView.$('li:first').append(childView.el);
    },

    events: {
        'click .js-node': 'toggle'
    },

    toggle: function(e) {
        var $e = $(e.currentTarget);

        $e.find(' > .tree-list').slideToggle();

    }

});

var TreeRootView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'tree-root',
    childView: TreeItemView
});


var theCollection = new TheCollection(obj_data);

App.getRegion('mainRegion').show( new TreeRootView({collection: theCollection}) );
```

Templates:

```
<div class="main-region">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="tree-template">
    <li class="js-node">
        <% if (item.children) { %>
            Click to toggle -
        <% } %>
        <%- item.title %>        
    </li>
</script>
```

Data:

```
var obj_data = {
    "title": "Ford",
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "Car",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Focus",
                },
                {
                    "title": "Taurus"   
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Truck",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "F-150"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your view has several nested elements with the `.js-node` class. When you click the parent one, you display the children `.js-node` elements, but when you click one of those, the event bubbles up and re-triggers the event on the parent `.js-node`, which closes the children that you just clicked.

You can stop this event bubbling by calling

`e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

I've updated your toggle method like so and it works:

```
toggle: function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
    $e.children('.tree-list').slideToggle();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/aeao3Lec/2/

<strike>The larger issue that I see is that your data is not really a collection... it's a tree. The CollectionView is really used to render a flat array of models, not a nested one. You should be rendering this data with multiple CollectionViews nested inside of each other... this will start to cause problems as your TreeItemView grows in complexity.</strike>

*Edit*: Nope, you're using a composite view which works perfectly for rendering trees.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm really interested in what you said about the data and the CollectionView.  I'm using the CollectionView as a base, and the CompositeView to render each branch of the tree.  I thought this would be a good use for the CompositeView.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Hrmmm, I didn't notice that. Yeah the composite view looks like the right one to use. I didn't notice that there was another view type used

Comment: Thanks Cory!  I think that I need a parent view for the compositview and so I just picked the CollectionView.  Thanks again!